# CoreData memory leak due to PrivateQueueConcurrencyType

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, memory-leaks

I discovered a memory leak today that manifested itself when calling **executeFetchRequest**  from my **main** **NSManagedObjectContext**. I finally discovered that the known offender was from having my NSManagedObjectContext having it’s parent context be assigned to a private managed object context.

Commenting out the line of code that has my main context assign a private parent class and instead directly be pointed to the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator frees my app of all memory leaks.

I was going off of the following article: http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/03/core-data-stack/ for a design pattern of how to implement CoreData inside my app. I really like the idea of having a private queue be dedicated to just writing disk, and having the main context as the single source for calling when working with the UI.

So my question is, has anybody else run into this problem, and if so do you know a fix instead of just working on one context only to avoid a memory leak?

Below is the section of my CoreDataStack that shows the two context vars.

```
private lazy var privateManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    return moc
  }()

  lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)

    // Commenting out  #1 and unCommening #2 prevents the leak from happening
    // However when the reverse happens and we create the private context, a memory leak occurs first thing in the app.

    // #1
    // managedObjectContext.parentContext = self.privateManagedObjectContext

    // And instead replace it with this line
    // #2
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator


    return managedObjectContext
  }()
```

Here is what I have for my save method using the main and private managed object context.

```
func save() {
    guard managedObjectContext.hasChanges || privateManagedObjectContext.hasChanges else {
      return
    }

    print("Going to save now")

    managedObjectContext.performBlockAndWait() {
      do {
        try self.managedObjectContext.save()
      } catch {
        fatalError("Error saving main managed object context! \(error)")
      }
    }

    privateManagedObjectContext.performBlock() {
      do {
        try self.privateManagedObjectContext.save()
      } catch {
        fatalError("Error saving private managed object context! \(error)")
      }
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private lazy var privateManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
  let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
  moc.parent = managedObjectContext // Set the receiver’s parent context
  return moc
}()
```

Perhaps this would solve it.

Comment: That is worth a shot. Sense posting this question, I actually refactored it using Realm. But I have a branch still using CoreData. In the next couple of days, I will pull down that branch and see if this resolves the memory leak.

Comment: In iOS10, background task are actually performed differently now anyway. Try using persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { } method which gives you a background context automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one correct way, but this is how I've implemented saving data in the background while updating the main context on the main thread.

Assign your main MOC (Managed Object Context) as `.MainQueueConcurrencyType`.
Assign your private MOC as `.PrivateQueueConcurrencyType` and its `parentContext` as the main MOC.

Save your private MOC on its background thread, then use the `performBlock` method on your main MOC to save its context, which will save your main MOC's context on the main thread. `performBlock` makes sure you're on the correct queue. Here is an example below, apologies for it being in Objective-C.

In my setup all of the changes are **ALWAYS** saved on the private MOC and then propagated to the main MOC. Great book on Core Data, which is actually in Swift at [objc.io](https://www.objc.io/) has many examples and advantages/disadvantages to different scenarios.

```
// Saving of your private and main context    
[[self class] saveContext:self.yourPrivateContext];

[self.yourPrivateContext.parentContext performBlock:^{
    [[self class] saveContext:self.yourPrivateContext.parentContext];
}];


+(BOOL)saveContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context{

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (context != nil) {  
        if ([context hasChanges] && ![context save:&error]) {   
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
            return NO;    
        } 
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Your answer makes complete sense and that is how Marcus Zarra showed how to do it in his article that I linked to in my question. As you can see from my code snippet above, my main's concurrency type is main and the private context's concurrency type is private. As for saving, I added my save method in the question. I believe it follows your suggestions. I'm starting to think this is a bug in swift.

Comment: You're saving your main MOC before your private MOC. I do the opposite. Are you making changes to both contexts or are you only writing to one context?

Comment: Only writing to the private after I save to the main. Because the private context would not have any context until the main pushes up to it. Furthermore I'm only saving in 3 places in the app delegate: WillResign, WillTerminate, and DidEnterBackground. So I'm not sure how the save method even plays into a memory leak when the app starts up.

Comment: Appreciate the determination and help. Looking into other possible reasons, but have spent 3 nights on this already and no luck. Luckily my needs for CoreData are very small and so saving just on main is not doing much of a performance hit.

Comment: Seems sound. Only thing I'd note is saving your main MOC pushes its changes to your private MOC which can potentially override unsaved changes in its context.